# How to fork your own repo in github?

Tags: github, git-submodules, git-fork

I have researched and all the answers I found say to just clone it and push it up under a different repo. Although this may work for many people it does not work for me.

I have a framework I made in a repo. I make websites based off of that. I update the framework regularly and need to be able to merge those changes into each website that uses it. I can't create branches for each website under the framework repo because I don't want my clients looking at other peoples websites.

I've tried submodules but you cannot have a submodule on the root folder.

I have also tried an organization account but you cannot fork a private repo into a free organization account. Any ideas on how I can set this up?

Comment: What features of a fork do you need that pushing manually to a new repo does not give you?

Comment: Also, frame challenge: make your framework into a library, and use submodules or a dependency manager (Composer. NPM, Nuget, etc, etc) to import it in your site projects.

Comment: the ability to easily update the framework on each website but just merging it in. 
its more of a starting point for my websites also so its more than just a library. It has everything I use to start a blank website quickly

Comment: I could be wrong and there might be a better way of doing it though, thats for sure

Comment: git is entirely decentralised, you can merge any two repostiories together that share some history (and even if they share *no* history!). The concept of a "fork" is just a button in Github's UI which creates a new copy of a repo, intended mostly for people to contribute to open source projects without having access to the main repo. So, have you tried just pushing to a new repo? What *Github-specific* feature could you then not use, whcih made you think you need a fork, specifically?

Comment: the github specific function that I havent been able to use is the ability to create a PR from framework into the website repo after framework has been updated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245327/discussion-between-bia-migueis-and-imsop).

Comment: OK, yes, I don't think you can raise a *pull request* between repositories if they're not marked as "forks" (although I've never tried), so you would need to perform the merge locally (by adding two "remotes" to your working copy).

Answer (score 2):

Github does not allow you to fork your own repos, your best bet is using an alt to fork your own repo and pushing whenever

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to create a second git account for yourself. This should allow PRs. Possible downside - the github account you're using is not immediately evident. A quick click on the "avatar" in the top right corner reveals the account. [Here](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/switching-between-accounts) is what github has to say about multiple accounts.